# What is "that" in "The Mouse that Roared"? e.g

Tags: parts-of-speech

I can't figure out if "that" in this construction is a conjunction, a preposition, or what, and therefore whether it should have an intial cap in headline style.

Comment: Just Google “The Mouse That Roared” and see how they capitalized it.( hint: it’s capitalized)

Comment: In traditional grammar it's a 'relative pronoun', which is to my mind a more accurate characterization than the newer 'subordinator'.

Comment: The trouble is, that it  doesn't work as a relative pronoun. For example, "The seat which they were sitting on" can be transformed to "The seat on which they were sitting", but "The seat that they were sitting on" cannot be transformed to "*The seat on that they were sitting". (There are other phenomena that show this as well, but I don't recall them). It is better analysed as a subordinator - the same "that" as in "He said **that** they were coming" and "I moved so **that** he could get past" - but in a relative clause at most one of "that" and the relative pronoun may be present.

Comment: @ColinFine The trouble is there are many arguments both ways, but none of them are conclusive. There are many relative words that cannot function as the complement of a preposition. One argument the other way: there is no subordinator whose presence is obligatory because of a random noun phrase not being overtly present in a subordinate clause, but whose optional when the phrase is overt. Such an analysis does not make sense. (for what it's worth I'm slightly more in favour of the subordinator view)

Comment: @Jim But in that style, which the OP is obviously not using, *every* word is always capitalised. So that does not help. In styles where not every word in the title is capitalised, you'll find that the word *that* is more often than not, *not* capitalised. See [here, for example](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mouse-that-Roared-Innocence-Expanded/dp/1442201436/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1459167389&sr=8-2&keywords=the+mouse+that+roared).

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "that" is a relative pronoun. The general rule is that all pronouns are capitalised in headline style.

It's a bit tricky to see the parts of speech at work because the sentence is missing a verb, e.g. "*It is* the mouse that roared". The word "that" acts as the subject of the verb "roared", and as a **pronoun** in the subordinate clause it refers or **relates** to the noun ("mouse") in the principle clause.

Answer (score 2):

In this phrase, the word "that" is a relative pronoun since it "relates" to and "replaces" the noun "mouse".

The rules of capitalization vary so much among the AP, Chicago, MTV, etc. that I figured I'd go to the source! It is capitalized in every mention I came across. The author's editors have spoken!